# Comment traduire « pimp my ride » ?

Tags: traduction, expressions, anglais

« Pimp my ride » était à l'origine le nom d'une [émission télé](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pimp_My_Ride) dont « le concept est de reprendre des vieilles voitures délabrées […] et de leur donner une esthétique bling bling ».

Comment former une traduction fidèle de cette expression ?

Answer (score 4):

As alluded to in Madlozoz’s answer, one French (in France) translation of the title of the TV show ([Pimp My Ride](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pimp_My_Ride)) is “Tune ma caisse.” In Quebec the show is also called “Pimp mon char.”

The “my ride” part of these two French translations (ma caisse/mon char) is good, for they both are familiar terms for “car/automobile” (voiture) (“my ride” = familiar term for “car/automobile” in English).

The “pimp” part, however, is not so good in my opinion.

The Quebec version is lacking in that it is just borrowing the English word, whereas the French version (tune[r]) is lacking in that it uses a word (again borrowed from English, but that’s not the main issue) that, to my knowledge, generally refers to adjusting (tuning) the engine or other mechanical aspects of a vehicle and not its outward appearance [but see the use of the noun “[tuning](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tuning)” (which was recently [Francified](http://tempsreel.nouvelobs.com/les-internets/20100331.OBS1686/eblabla-et-bolidage-pour-remplacer-chat-et-tunning.html) as the noun “[boldiage](http://dictionnaire.reverso.net/francais-definition/bolidage)”) to include outward appearance].

Converting “pimp my ride” first to “plain” English results literally in “turn my car into a [pimpmobile](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pimpmobile)”(i.e., a car suitable for a pimp), but it has been expanded to mean “[customize](http://onlineslangdictionary.com/meaning-definition-of/pimp-%28one%27s%29-ride) [the appearance of] my car” in general, even when the goal isn’t necessarily to make it look suitable for pimping.

Therefore, for the “pimp” part of the phrase, I think “***[personnalise](http://dictionnaire.reverso.net/anglais-francais/customize)* ma caisse/mon char**” would capture well the expanded meaning and for a more familiar way to say “customize,” there is “deck out” or “trick out,” which could translate to “***orne*/*décore*/*pare* mon char** ([pare](http://dictionnaire.reverso.net/anglais-francais/deck%20out) even rhymes!)/**ma caisse**.”

(To maintain the literal meaning of “pimp” and “pimpmobile” you might be able to work with “[maque](https://www.google.com/search?q=maque%20meaning%20french&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8)” to arrive at ”pare mon char en maquemobile” =  “maque ma caisse/mon char,” but this would require coining a verb from “maque” as well as “maquemobile”, just as "tune ma caisse" requires coining a verb from the French nouns 'tuner' or 'tuning')

Comment: Pourquoi une réponse en anglais?

Comment: @AlexisWilke Thanks for pointing that out. I truly wish that my French was good enough to answer and comment here in it exclusively (but please note that I always try to ask my questions in both French and English), but my concern is that my often rambling answers and comments in my flawed French would be [even] harder to decipher by the majority of the good people reading them than they [sometimes already] are when framed in my first language.

Comment: Just so you known, "tuning" in French (in France at least) is not used in the meaning of "fine-tuning" but exactly in the sense of customizing the appearance. It was borrowed, true, but not faithful to its origin. To convince yourself, just Google "voiture tuning". Therefore "Tune ma caisse" could be a correct translation for France.

Comment: @Chop Thanks for clarifying that for me! (I wasn't sure & that's why I added the "But see" link to "tuning" in paragraph 4). In my last sentence I also mention coining a verb from “tuning” & I wonder if the fact that “tune ma caisse” could be a correct translation in this case means that forming verbs from other nouns borrowed from English gerunds could also be correct (at least in familiar usage): 'parke ma caisse'/'shop[p]e pour une caisse'/'brushe mes tifs'/'presse mes fringues', for example? Thanks again & any help you could provide on the "verb coinage" issue would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @PapaPoule I don't think there is a rule of thumb about this. I don't think I've ever heard the examples you give. Often, we borrow the word because it is a notion that does not exist yet in French or is not fully reflected by the French translation. Most people will not associate "tuning" and "personnalisation". New technologies is a field where we borrow much and the Académie Française comes most times with a translation some time later, but it is hard to switch once the habit has kicked in (people still prefer "e-mail" over "courriel" and "cloud" over "nuage").

Answer (score 3):

On a déjà eu le participe passé du verbe [*pi[m]pelorer*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/dmf/pimpelorer?idf=dmfXfXrmXpchj;str=0) utilisé en adjectif en français pour « *[o]rné, enjolivé (en partic. d'une broderie)* » (*Dmf*), un peu comme en anglais<sup>1</sup> - et assurément avant l'automobile :

> *La seconde chose qui fort me gree et est neccessaire a ma forge si est ung grant tignel ou palais long et large, et une haulte table
> couverte de deux nappes subtiles, l'une pinpeloree, la table bien
> garnie et adornee de grant plante de viandes delicieuses et plusieurs
> entremes...* (MÉZIÈRES, *Songe vieil pèl. C.*, t.1, c.1386-1389, 321).
>
> [ *Dictionnaire du moyen français* - Dmf ]

Il y a sans doute un lien à faire avec l'adjectif [*pimpant*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/pimpant). Comme on l'a remarqué dans une autre [réponse](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/13811), la [*personnalisation automobile*](http://granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=2070094) (voir [*Franceterme*](http://www.culture.fr/franceterme/result?francetermeSearchTerme=tuning)) est un terme à préférer pour *tuning/customizing*. Dans un article sur l'anglicisme [*revamper*](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?id=2983), dont le sens est parfois [apparenté](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/revamp), on note :

> Lorsqu'on parle d'objets, de pièces ou d'immeubles, on peut
> employer les verbes *rénover*, *remodeler*, *retoucher*, *retaper*, *refaçonner*
> ou la locution *remettre à neuf*. Lorsqu'on veut insister sur la
> nouveauté, on peut préférer *renouveler*, *rajeunir*, *rafraîchir* ou
> *moderniser*.
>
> [ *Banque de dépannage linguistique* (BDL) ]

Le verbe [*retaper*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/retaper) (avec [*retape*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/retape)) a déjà eu historiquement des connotations reliées à la prostitution, mais c'est assez usuel pour rendre l'idée de « redonner un aspect neuf »; [*rhabiller*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/rhabiller) a quant à lui un sens technique intéressant de rebâtir (le revêtement) à partir de la structure primitive. On a plusieurs choix, tout comme pour l'automobile.<sup>2</sup>

On peut aussi parler de [*transformation*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/transformation) pour un changement de caractère ou de [*métamorphose*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/m%C3%A9tamorphose) quand il y a un changement extérieur important. Enfin, le verbe [*arranger*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/arranger) comporte un sens de « *[d]isposer, mettre dans l'ordre, quelquefois avec une recherche esthétique; orner, parer.* »; par exemple conjugué à l'impératif quand un objet est brisé et qu'il requiert une manipulation particulière qu'on demande à quelqu'un...

---

> **Suggestions pour les producteurs télé :**
>  « Pimpelore » ma bagnole ! [!!]
>  Retape mon antique guimbarde ! [!]
>  Métamorphose d'automobile. 
>  Rhabille-moi une voiture ! 
>  Arrange mon char ! [Qc; plus fam.: *arrange-moi le char !*]

---

<sub>1. Comme l'indique l'[article](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pimp_My_Ride), la référence très contemporaine est celle du comportement du *proxénète*. Personnage parasitaire dont souvent le [mauvais goût](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/gout) ostentatoire (« *Il était bien loin, sans doute, de ce technicien méticuleux qui prodiguait sur ses fresques en relief, avec un mauvais goût pervers et candide, des ornements de métal et des pierres transparentes*. » (Faure, *Hist. art*, 1914, p. 401)., *TLFi*) se reflète autant dans l'automobile que dans le choix d'habillement de sa « protégée » - l'être humain dont il fait la traite auprès d'autres exploiteurs. À première vue, l'[étymologie](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=pimp&allowed_in_frame=0) du mot est incertaine... Les dictionnaires offrent un traitement variable des verbes qui y sont associés. *Collins* est à l'avant garde avec [*to pimp up/pimp out*](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/pimp-up) (« *(transitive, adverb) to make (someone or something, esp a car) more extravagantly decorated, as with flashy accessories, etc* - *C20: from the extravagant clothing and vehicles popularly associated with pimps* ») sans mention de registre informel mais avec une entrée indépendante au verbe [*to pimp*](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/pimp) avec « *(transitive) (slang) to adapt or embellish in an ostentatious manner* », similaire à ce qu'on retrouve sur [*AmE*](https://ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=pimp&submit.x=0&submit.y=0). *Cambridge* a un sens du verbe [to pimp](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/pimp?q=pimped) tout court pour *décoration*. [Merriam-W.](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pimp) n'a aucun autre sens que celui du criminel essentiellement. *ODO* a le [verbe](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/learner/pimp) utilisé informellement. Dans plusieurs cas on indique une étymologie inconnue ou incertaine.</sub>

<sub>2. Pour l'automobile/la voiture, bien on a la [*bagnole*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/bagnole), la [*caisse*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/caisse), le [*tacot*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/tacot), la [*guimbarde*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/guimbarde), ou le [*char*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/char) au Québec, ainsi que le [bazou](http://granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=8362180) et la [*minoune*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/minoune) (on pourrait utiliser [*monture*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/monture) pour la moto).</sub>

Answer (score 2):

Traduction bonne mais pas du tout littérale :

> Tune ma caisse !

Traduction littérale mais très mauvaise :

> Donnez à mon allure ce *je ne sais quoi* de proxénète

Mot pour mot:

- to pimp = faire maquereau, rendre maquereau
- my ride = mon trajet (dans un véhicule)

Comment: "Ride" is slang for "car" here. It doesn't mean _un trajet_.